# rails undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following the tutorial found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). It's simple, and I've followed the instructions exactly to step 6.7. At this point, I get the error

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

when I try to access index.html.erb on the rails server.

I know the database is working fine, because I can do everything mentioned in step 6.3, create new posts and show/edit/destroy them with absolutely no problems.

Specifically, the issue is with the line

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
```

and it's essentially claiming that `@posts` is nil.

I appreciate any help for this ROR newbie! Thanks.

**index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Hello, Rails!</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Content</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.name %></td>
    <td><%= post.title %></td>
    <td><%= post.content %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
                                     :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to "My Blog", posts_path %>
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you do `@foo = "bar"` in the controller and then successfully do `<%= @foo %>` in the view?

Comment: is that index.html.erb located inside views/posts/ or somewhere else ?

Comment: @JasonSwett I don't get an error, but "bar" doesn't show up on the page. This index.html.erb is located in views/home/. Should I try it with views/posts/index.html.erb instead?

Comment: Your views must be inside the respective controller directory. If your method is `index` inside the `PostsController`, your `index.html.erb` should be inside `views/posts/`.

Comment: Oh wow, clearly I don't understand how ROR really works! Lucas Nogueira is totally right - this fixes it. Do you all think that the tutorial I'm using is good? Or is there a better one that you would recommend?

Comment: ~MrYoshiji, no if he never created a Post, then Post.all will return [].

Comment: I will create an answer since it helped you and put a tutorial I like there =)

Comment: Can you type in the full stack trace which shows up on the error page ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order for the `views` to work fine in Rails they must be inside the correct directory. This is one of the many implementations of the so called "[Convention over Configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration)" that Rails loves.

So, if you have a method `index` and this method is inside a controller named `PostsController`, you must have a view named `index` inside the directory `views/posts/`. This way, Rails will know that it have to render this view when a get to this method is processed.

About a good tutorial, I would recommend this [one](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book). It is extense and covers a lot of things that are not just related to Rails itself, like deploying on Heroku and a little CSS.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd been trying to piece together elements about Heroku and Git, but this seems to tie it all together like you said. Thanks again! I'd upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I upvoted it for him ha. Just one more thing though: you can render any view (or partial) you'd like from an action with the `render` command. So, for example, if for some reason you really needed your `index.html.erb` file to be in `views/home`, in your index action of your posts controller you could type: `render "home/index"`.

Comment: Well said @MrDanA. But since he is just starting, I though would be better to stay simple on the final answer :)

Comment: I agree! I hope Jonathan will keep it mind in the future though!

Comment: The tutorial I posted covers partials so I have high hopes he will notice it soon enough!

Comment: Yep, I've started working through the tutorial you posted. Thanks for all the advice guys! Knowing how learning new languages goes, you can probably expect to see me here again :)