# Show a partial and index in another directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two scaffolds

- users
- userscuentas

I want to show in the file `app/views/users/_layout_form.html.erb` the files `app/views/userscuentas/index.html.erb` and `app/views/userscuentas/new.html.erb`. I have it this way in the `file app/views/users/_layout_users.html.erb`:

```
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
            <p>
                <%= render :file => "/userscuentas/index.html.erb" %>
            </p>
        </div>
```

The index file is in default when normally we generate the scaffold, then this way are the models:

- app/models/user.rb

  ```
  has_many :userscuentas, :dependent => :destroy
  ```
- app/models/userscuentas.rb

  ```
  belongs_to :user
  ```

and routes.rb is like this:

```
resources :users do
    resources :userscuentas
end
```

I got this error:

```
NoMethodError at /users/1/edit
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

The file controller userscuentas_controller.rb has this:

```
@userscuentas = @user.userscuentas.all
```

I don't know what to do.

Comment: where is your edit file ?

Comment: In the users directory, It has the normal structure when we generate the scaffold users/edit.html.erb but from where I want to show the index userscuenta's file is in users/_layout_users.html.erb

Comment: You need to show more code that is related to the problem. The error message probably indicates a file it's referring to. If not, at least show the `edit` method in your controller.

Comment: `NoMethodError at /users/1/edit

undefined method each' for nil:NilClass ` this error is saying that in your edit file. there is an each word but he don't recognize it , so we need to see this in your question in order to help you.

Comment: this is the code, what else do you need ?
http://pastebin.com/PuX5JheJ

Comment: edit page is render layout_user , where the code of layout_user ?

Comment: there is in the pastebin # --------------------------------- app/views/users/layout_users.html.erb---------------------- and it has the render                     <%= render :file => "/userscuentas/index.html.erb" %>

Comment: Can somebody else help me with this ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this line in your userscuentas controller

```
  def index
        @userscuentas = @user.userscuentas.all
    end
```

try to make it

```
  def index
        @userscuentas = Userscuenta.all
    end
```

Comment: I tried with this but doesn't work, continue the same problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015769/rails-undefined-method-each-for-nilnilclass same problem.

Comment: I think is not the same because the file userscuentas/index.html.erb must be there, shouldn't be in another directory, so i just need to render it from another scaffold :/

Comment: i am still looking for the error , but just keep your index action defined as the general way @userscuentas = Userscuenta.all

Comment: do you have the application on github ?

Comment: or I give the team viewer number if you want

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37071/discussion-between-andru1989-and-dexter)

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess is that your userlayout is being called by a controller method that does not set `@userscuentas`, and so in line 1 of `userscuentas/index.html.erb` you get a `NoMethodError` in `<% @userscuentas.each do |userscuenta| %>` because it is null.

Add a `before_filter` to user_controller, and in the filter's method set `@userscuentas`.

---

You should **learn how to debug in rails**.
Also, the error will tell you the exact line where it is being thrown. You should look into that information, and share it when you post this type of questions.