# render from another index scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I continue with this problem

[Another Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709873/show-a-partial-and-index-in-another-directory/18710133?noredirect=1#comment27568260_18710133)

But somebody told me that if i want i can pass parameteres in the render, but i dont know how to do it, I mean here

```
<%= render :file => "userscuentas/index" %>
```

SO maybe I can pass the @userscuentas as parameteres
I really need your help

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to render a partial?

Comment: no i'm trying to render a file called index.html.erb but I also rename the file like this _index.html.erb using render partial but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file trying to be rendered is a partial, try this:

```
<%= render 'userscuentas/index', :userscuentas => @userscuentas %>
```

You can then access the variable in the partial using `usercuentas`

**EDIT**

For the partial, do the following to prevent the nil error:

```
<% if !userscuentas.nil? %>

   #Do whatever you have to do here

<% end %>
```

Comment: I got this error Missing template userscuentas/index with {:locale=>[:es], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :buil so if I rename the file like a partial got this undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: First did you rename index.html.erb to _index.html.erb? Also, are you sure the path to the file is correct?

Comment: Yes i rename the file _index.html.erb using render partial or just render
And i rename the file index.html.erb using render file

Comment: So after renaming the partial, you get an a nil error? Can you post the code in the partial?

Comment: The partial or the file has the normal structure when we generate the scaffold, just <% @userscuentas.each do |userscuenta| %>bla bla bla <% end %> and the controller in the method index has 

userscu.. = Usercuenta.all and i has the relation good between the models look the files here http://pastebin.com/PuX5JheJ

Comment: <% @userscuentas.each do |userscuenta| %> should be <% userscuentas.each do |userscuenta| %> because we passed the instance variable to the partial with the local variable usercuentas

Comment: now i got this error undefined local variable or method `userscuentas' for #<#<Class:0xac7360c>:0xac632d4> is not passing the parameters

Comment: I made an a grammatical error in the previous code. I updated it. Try it now.

Comment: Yes I was looking for that too,but I Got The same problem again undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass, i have it this, 
<%= render 'userscuentas/index', :userscuentas => @userscuentas %>
and the partial this way
<% userscuentas.each do |userscuenta| %>

Comment: My best guess would be that @usercuentas is nil in the first place. Check to see if that is true.

Comment: At this moment it not has registers in that table, but it's normal because a user maybe doesn't have a usercuenta, so it's empty, i think this should be working

Comment: That's exactly the problem, you can't call each for a nil variables. Check the new updated code

Comment: it doesn't show an error but It's not working because in the table there are 3 registers, but i doesn't show anything, always is nil, so the parameters are not passing

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. In what view are you trying to render the partial?

Answer (score 0):

From your http://pastebin.com/PuX5JheJ

change app/views/userscuentas/index.html.erb to

```
<%= render "list", :userscuentas => @userscuentas %>
```

then make a NEW file called app/views/userscuentas/_list.html.erb with this code

```
<% userscuentas.each do |userscuenta| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to userscuenta.id, userscuenta_path(userscuenta) %></td>
        <td><%= userscuenta.nombre %></td>
        <td><%= userscuenta.nro_cuenta %></td>
        <td><%= userscuenta.tipo_cuenta %></td>
        <td><%= userscuenta.user_id %></td>
        <td><%=l userscuenta.created_at %></td>
        <td>
          <%= link_to t('.edit', :default => t("helpers.links.edit")),
                      edit_userscuenta_path(userscuenta), :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
          <%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
                      userscuenta_path(userscuenta),
                      :method => :delete,
                      :data => { :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')) },
                      :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

You will also have to change how you are calling it in app/views/users/layout_users.html.erb
Also make sure (after you have changed this) that the @userscuentas variable is set in the controller action that references this view.

```
 <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Cuentas</a></li>

       <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
           <p>
               <%= render "userscuentas/list", :userscuentas => @userscuentas %>
           </p>
       </div>
```

I'm kind of unsure about the structure of your application, but your new.html.erb will also not work in the way you are calling that partial because you have to set the @usersuentas variable before it will render properly. You are also calling there a view, and not a partial.

app/views/users/new.html.erb

```
<%= render "userscuentas/list", :userscuentas => @userscuentas %>
```

This is assuming you have to populate your @userscuentas variable in the controller side as well, so

userscuentas_controller.rb

```
 def new
    @userscuentas = @user.userscuentas.all
    @userscuenta = Userscuenta.new
 end
```

Comment: I got this error Missing template userscuentas/index with {:locale=>[:es], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :buil so if I rename the file like a partial got this undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass, the thing is that those are two diferents scaffold and i want to show de index file from the users scaffold

Comment: can you post the code inside the partial? It is likely you are trying to loop through a variable that doesn't exist. Can you make sure that in the partial you are looping through <%= userscuentas.each do |u| %> like that?

Comment: look the files pastebin.com/PuX5JheJ 
the file has the normal structure when we generate the scaffold

Comment: Okay from the pastebin it seems you aren't using the partial properly let me change my answer to help you out.